# (US) Buying from private party — husband selling wife's car. Sign title while on facetime?

Tags: buying

So I'm looking at this car.

The price is very good. Almost too good to be true — the normal asking price for this car at this mileage is 8500-10000, this guy sells it for 7500. The maintenance records are impressive — serviced at a dealer every 5000 miles like clockwork. The papers about the service records show the same name as the one on the title. The car is pretty clean (it's a 2007 Lexus ES350).

The problem is — the title is in the seller's wife name (or so he says — but their last names seem to match). And she's in another state across the country. He's proposing he overnights the title to his wife so that she signs it over, while on the facetime with me.

The guy seems legit overall. If he's a scammer then he's really good at it.
The whole thing sounds fishy to me, but also I can't poke any holes in this deal. It all makes sense. If his wife was in front of me and willing to sign the title, I'd buy it in a heartbeat right there. I wouldn't even say that something doesn't feel right about this guy. But still hesitating.

He did ask me to take the car and pay the money on the spot and deal with the title later, which I refused. He did suggest to sign the title himself, which I also refused.

Would you do it if you were in this situation?

Comment: Sorry but this question is off-topic for this site. I'd suggest that you consider one that focuses more on legal advice. That's outside our purview.

Answer (score 0):

People sure seem to do some strange things, but it doesn't always mean it's malicious.  I would do it if the wife provided a photo of herself holding her legible ID and the signed title along with it.  I would also have her provide a Bill of Sale.

Facetime (unless recorded) doesn't give you tangible proof in case of a legal issue.

Comment: If a deal sounds too good to be true, it probably is...